# Adding to a List from a different Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

When passing a `List<T>` to a **single** Thread that appends to that `List`, and making sure, that the Runnable of this Thread has **finished executing** (i need to interrupt it midway and get the data computed up to that point), is it safe to use the `List` from the calling thread?

I used this method in my code and it seems to work, but i can't shake the feeling that I am only getting lucky, since the data in my list is not volatile and the list itself does not provide synchronized access.

Am i better off using a `Collections.synchronizedList(..)` as an accumulator and copy the contents when i need the list in my main thread (after interrupting the computational thread)?

Code Example:

```
List<MyData> accList = new ArrayList<>();
Future<?> compFuture = executor.submit(new ComputationRunnable(accList));
// The Runnable will add elements to the List
compFuture.cancel(true);
// Interrupt is caught in the Runnable and it returns null
// Try Future.get() to see if the Future was correctly cancelled, ignore Exception
compFuture.get();
useList(accList);
```

Comment: What is your definition of "save"? Obviously it doesn't matter if computations are complete ...

Comment: your use case is not clear, can you show some code to allow us to better understand your issue?

Comment: Added a short breakdown of my code.

Comment: What do you mean by the thread having "finished". I see no Thread objects in your code. Are you actually asking about the semantics of executors?

Comment: I'd say it is safe. You cancel the Task, so it is not working on the list any more and it was the only "other" Thread to hold a reference to it. So, yes - no further synchronization required.

Comment: Is memory consistency negligible if I only add and not change any of the elements?

Comment: How about this: the code _may be safe_ but it does not _look like it's safe_ for the following reasons: 1) It reads like you share an unsynchronized object between threads 2) The side effects, that mutate accList aren't foreseeable 3) The overall approach looks cumbersome (e.g. why doesn't compFuture just return MyData?) 4) The code snippet is just an invite for wild-guessing.

Answer (score 0):

this is because the List is not made for multithreading

you can use a [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) for example....

More info can be found direct by oracle:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html